# How to include header files (.h) created in a project from source files (.cpp) in Visual 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have created a header file in a project. In the same project I have a source (.cpp) file.

I have no idea how to declare/include that header file in my source file.

I'm using Visual 2010.

Comment: Using a `#include "MyHeader.h"` preprocessor directive?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line at the top of the .cpp file:

```
#include "yourheaderfile.h"
```

Comment: That's pretty bad advice in a VS2010 project.  Please don't guess at an answer.

Comment: Please, tell me why.

Comment: Just try it for yourself.  Use a project template and do what you recommended.  And you'll see that the #include is completely skipped and has no effect, the precompiled header file must be first.

Comment: Okay, I tried it, but with VS2013 because I dont have a VS2010 installation anymore. I had no problem. Header file and content is recognized. I am doing this for two years now, and I didnt have any problems with it.

Answer (score -1):

At the top of you .CPP file write

```
#include "header.h"
```

Make sure the appropriate vc++, c++, and linker options are set in the project settings. Default settings are usually enough for a from-scratch project

Comment: Isn't `#include <stdafx.h>` supposed to be at top in VS projects?